# Spinner with parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I want to get a list from parse.com and set it to a spinner that I have created

I have already used this code but it returns items in the spinner in this format

> com.parse.ParseObject@132610f4

```
final Spinner country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.schoolSelect);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("school");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,list);
                country.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

does anyone know how to get a certain column only in the query and let the data inside it to be displayed 
the column that i want to get it's content is called

> SchoolName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create another list to store the name of your `ParseObject`

```
final Spinner country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.schoolSelect);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("school");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(ParseObject object : list) {
                 nameList.add(object.getString("SchoolName"));
            }
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,nameList);
            country.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah if you have any issue then let me know.